Jquery/JavaScript: Make Elements Appear in Order
I want to create an effect, where when a user scrolls to a certain Div, elements within it appear in order, starting from the left-most element to the right-most. I've been successful with just making multiple elements appear if a user scrolls vertically to a certain div, now I am trying achieve showing elements within a div show in a certain order.
Here is what I have tried so far. Before I get to the Jquery aspect, I gave each of the elements/their classes CSS displays of "none" and just use the .show() function in Jquery. These are all just placeholder names used in this example expect for gmp-map, or a Google Map.
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {

    if (this.window.scrollY >= 116) {
        const div = $(".div");
        const divImg = $(".div>.col>img");
        const map = $("gmp-map");
    
        function showDiv1Elements() {
          divImg.show();
        }
    
        function showDiv2Elements() {
          map.show();
        }
    
    
        div.on(scrollY, showDiv1Elements);
        div.on(scrollY, showDiv2Elements);
    
    }

});


You can use the .slideXXX() functions to show an item gradually, and .then() to show the next item after this completes.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].
